# How do I open and use old ANSI C code from 1996 on a Mac?

Tags: c, xcode, macos, gsm, ansi-c

For a uni project I have to use the ANSI C code supplied in the GSM speech coding standard from 1996. 
the zip archive can be found here
https://portal.3gpp.org/desktopmodules/Specifications/SpecificationDetails.aspx?specificationId=281

I have a MacBook Pro running OS X 10.11.6.

when trying to compile all the different files in its /C directory (main directory) with xcode installed in terminal using clang:

```
clang dtx.c err_conc.c globdefs.c gsm_hr.c homing.c host.c mathdp31.c mathhalf.c sp_dec.c sp_enc.c sp_frm.c SP_rom.c sp_sfrm.c utils.c vad.c male.inp -o GSMHR
```

it gives multiple errors like:

```
In file included from dtx.c:37:
./mathhalf.h:75:11: warning: incompatible redeclaration of library function 'round' [-Wincompatible-library-redeclaration]
Shortword round(Longword L_var1);      /* 1 ops */
```

I assume this is because of the new compiler having functions defined that weren't defined back then?

Anyways, what is the easiest way for me to make this code usable?

Comment: did the `-std=c89` option fail you somehow?

Comment: When I did similar work, I used "sed" to rename all conflicting functions in the downloaded files.

Answer (score -2):

POSIX (and other standardisation bodies) define a C function `round` that takes and returns a floating point type. The function `round` that seems to be declared in your `mathhalf.h` file is probably implemented in the `mathhalf.c` file and takes and returns *integer* types (32 and 16 bits, apparently). This function clashes with the `round` that comes with the compiler.

Assuming the function is implemented in `mathhalf.c`, simply rename it to, for example, `intRound` in both the .c and the .h file.

Comment: Is a 1996 mac posix?

Comment: @user3528438 No, but a 201x MacOS X with clang is. Nobody has been talking about a 1996 Mac.

Comment: yes searching through all files and changing everything to rounded() worked. i also got confused with how to pass comand line arguments to it but i figured it out now. thank you